# How to assign a same number of business day as Monday to weekend days

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, business-intelligence

I have a date dimension table where i need to add NumberofBusinessDay column which will tell me the number of business day it is. For example:

```
Date        WeekendFlag  BusinessDayFlag  **NumberofBusinessDay** 
01/01/2015  N            N                0
01/02/2015  N            Y                1
01/03/2015  Y            N                2
01/04/2015  Y            N                2
01/05/2015  N            Y                2
```

I have assigned the number of business days to the weekdays but I am struggling with assigning a number to a weekend day which will be the same as following business day - Monday (in case Monday is a holiday, it will be Tuesday), as shown in above table. Here it what I have so far:

```
Date        WeekendFlag  BusinessDayFlag  **NumberofBusinessDay** 
01/01/2015  N            N                0
01/02/2015  N            Y                1
01/03/2015  Y            N                NULL
01/04/2015  Y            N                NULL
01/05/2015  N            Y                2
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated

My query for assigning BusinessDays for weekdays (only 2015 data):

```
SELECT Date, WeekendFlag, BusinessDayFlag
       ,NumberofBusinessDay = CASE WHEN WeekendFlag = 'N' THEN 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY YearCode, MonthCode ORDER BY WeekendFlag, Date ASC) 
       END
INTO #test
FROM DimDate
WHERE Date between '01/01/2015' AND '12/31/2015' --for testing purposes only
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Just an FYI - purpose for accounting weekends as business days is because we don't want to miss any activities that happens during weekend (its a possibility) and we want to count those actitivies in the next business day.

Comment: If you have one of the latest versions of SQL Server you can use the LEAD function

Comment: What do you do for Mondays that are not-business days?

Comment: select case when DATENAME(dw,date)  IN ('Saturday','SUNDAY') THEN NULL ELSE date END from table

Comment: @Sachu I have posted the query

Comment: @Dan Guzman It is basically the following business day, in this case it would be Tuesday.

Comment: @cha I have 2012 version, I will research on how to use LEAD, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check with below sql

```html
---- below code will crete table for businessday calculation
create table dimension  (calenderdate date,WeekendFlag  char(1) ,BusinessDayFlag   char(1),NumberofBusinessDay int)

declare  @yearstartdate date
declare  @yearenddate date

SELECT   @yearstartdate = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0) 
SELECT   @yearenddate =DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()) + 1, -1)

while datediff (dd,@yearstartdate,DATEADD(DD,1,@yearenddate)) <>0
begin
 insert into dimension 
 select @yearstartdate ,
 case when datename(DW,@yearstartdate) = 'SUNDAY' or datename(DW,@yearstartdate) = 'SATURDAY'
 then 'Y' else 'N' end,
 case when datename(DW,@yearstartdate) = 'SUNDAY' or datename(DW,@yearstartdate) = 'SATURDAY'
 then 'N' else 'Y' end,
 null

 set @yearstartdate = dateadd(dd,1,@yearstartdate)
end
-----verify table
SELECT * FROM dimension 

-----calculate NumberofBusinessDay number  from below code

;with ctebusinessday
as
(
 select calenderdate,
sum(
case when BusinessDayFlag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end
   ) over (order by calenderdate) as NOfBusinessDay
   from dimension 
)
update b
set b.NumberofBusinessDay =c.NOfBusinessDay
from dimension  b join ctebusinessday c
on b.calenderdate = c.calenderdate
  
  
update dimension 
set NumberofBusinessDay = NumberofBusinessDay + 1
where weekendflag = 'Y'
--verify table
select * from dimension
```

you can update  any date as businessday or weekend day and calculate NumberofBusinessDay  from NumberofBusinessDay  calculation code part .   i marked only saturaday as  weekend day and populated table

Thanks

Comment: thank you sooo  much!! this worked great. I didn't even think of a simple logic - "update table set businessday = businessday +1 where weekendflag =Y ". I am just going to update the holidays to 0. Again thank you!!

Comment: I added a partition function by YearCode and MonthCode before order by in CTE. This will give number of business days for each month not the whole year.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can do this with a cumulative sum:

```
select dd.*,
       sum(case when BusinessDayFlag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by date) as NumberOfBusinessDay
from DateDimension;
```

You can put this in an update as:

```
with toupdate as (
      select dd.*,
             sum(case when BusinessDayFlag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by date) as newNumberOfBusinessDay
      from DateDimension
     )
update toupdate
    set NumberOfBusinessDay = newNumberOfBusinessDay;
```

In earlier versions of SQL Server, you can do something similar using `cross apply`.

EDIT:

Based on your sample data, your seem to be counting the number of *weekdays*, not *business days*.  If so, the above is just using the wrong variable:

```
with toupdate as (
      select dd.*,
             sum(case when WeekEndFlag = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by date) as newNumberOfBusinessDay
      from DateDimension
     )
update toupdate
    set NumberOfBusinessDay = newNumberOfBusinessDay;
```

This is based on your sample results.  Note that this is probably off-by-1, so you should subtract 1.  From the description, though, I don' understand why the first row has a value of 0 and not 1.

Comment: This didn't work, I am trying to understand what your query is doing. I did that only for the year of 2015, it assigned the following numbers: 'Jan-1 = 0, Jan-2 = 0, Jan-3 = 1, Jan-4 = 2, Jan-5 = 2, Jan-6 = 2, Jan-7 = 2, Jan-8 = 2, Jan-9 = 2, Jan-10 = 3, Jan-11 = 4'